# python JIRA connection with proxy

Tags: python, jira, basic-authentication, python-jira

I'm trying to connect via python-jira using a proxy:

```
server = {"server": "https://ip:port/jira",
          'proxies': {"http": "http://ip:port", "https": "http://ip:port"},
          'verify': False,
          'stream': True}

cls.jira_object = JIRA(options=server,
                       basic_auth=(user, password),
                       validate=True)
```

Traceback error:

```
tests\jira_test\ticket_test.py:52: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\jira\client.py:217: in __init__
    ???
build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\jira\client.py:1841: in session
    ???
build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\jira\utils.py:78: in json_loads
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

r = None, verb = '???', kwargs = {}, request = None, headers = None

>   ???
E   JIRAError: JiraError HTTP None
```

Any idea how to allow jira-python to connect with proxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide the proxy to the constructor of JIRA:

```
cls.jira_object = JIRA(options=server,
                       basic_auth=(user, password),
                       validate=True,
                       proxies={"http": "http://ip:port", "https": "http://ip:port"})
```

Remember to remove the "proxies" from your options dict

More info about the constructor:
https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/develop/jira/client.py

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in python3.

```
server =  {'server': 'https://<jira.url.com>','proxies':"http://%s:%s@<ip>:<port>"%(proxy_user,proxy_password),'verify':True}

jira_object = JIRA(options=server,basic_auth=(jira_user,jira_password),                     validate=True)
```

Another option :

```
import os
from jira import JIRA 

os.environ['https_proxy']='<proxy url>:<port>'
os.environ['http_proxy']='<proxy url>:<port>'
con = JIRA(basic_auth=(<username>,<password>),options={'server':'<jira_url>'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to set "HTTPS_PROXY" environment variable.
I did it this way :

```
import os
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"]="https://genproxy:8080"
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"]="http://ip:port"
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like it requires bit of a magic. [Have a look here at this answer.](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/226857/using-python-jira-through-a-proxy-server?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fanswers.atlassian.com%2Fquestions%2F226857%2Fusing-python-jira-through-a-proxy-server&application=acac)

Here's code:

```
my_jira = JIRA(jira_options, basic_auth=(jira_admin, jira_passwd))
my_jjira._session.proxies = {'http': '127.0.0.1:8888', 'https': '127.0.0.1:8888' }
```