# Accessing Jira REST api running behind apache proxy

Tags: python, jira

I am trying to connect to Jira REST API running behind apache proxy. I tried to use python-jira module for this task and it worked fine as far as I was connecting to Jira directly, bypassing apache proxy authorization. However, with apache proxy up I am steadily getting "Err: 401 Unauthorized" error.

the problem is that I need to provide authorization credentials twice, one for proxy and one for Jira.

All tests had been done on my local VM.

- apache proxy is running on standard port 80 and redirects 127.0.0.1/jira to 127.0.0.1:8080/jira
- jira us running on port 8080

Here is the working curl command where:

- jirauser - jira user to use for authorization jirapass
- jirapassword to use for authorization
- dGVzdDp3d3c= - is base64 encoded proxyuser:proxypass string

it is actually running and producing results

```
curl -u 'jirauser:jirapass' -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp3d3c=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://127.0.0.1/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=key=DEV4"
```

for the python-jira module I think that I need to tweak 'options' parameter to add to 'headers' list the "Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp3d3c=" but somehow it doesn't work.

```
from jira import JIRA, JIRAError
import sys

username="Jira_username"
password="Jira_password"

jira_options = {
   'server': 'http://127.0.0.1/jira',
   'verify': True,
    'headers' : {
                        'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check',
                        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Token token="dGVzdDp3d3c\="'
                }
}
try:
     jira = JIRA(
                 options    = jira_options,
                 basic_auth = (username,password),
                 validate   = True,
            )

except JIRAError as e:
     print("Failed in Jira connection initialisation with error [%s]" % e)
     sys.exit()
```

I also tried to do a direct call with requests librarty

r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=key=DEV4',auth=('jirauser','jirapass'),headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': "Basic %s" % "dGVzdDp3d3c="})

but the result again was: 401 Error

I am getting really confused on why curl command works but python code fails what is wrong here? (since curl is working I assume this is not an issue in environment setup)

Comment: Have you tried removing the Authorization headers? It seems like that is in conflict with the basic_auth. When I have connected to jira I normally don't pass in an extra options and don't have any issues.

Comment: I started my tests without Authorization header and it did not work. The problem is that I need first to pass through proxy authorization (and that's where I have found I need the Authorization header) and then pass through Jira authorization with basic_auth. The CURL request I showed above works. The problem is how to make python do the same work. That's when I start trying to insert Authorization parameter to headers.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872740/python-jira-connection-with-proxy

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
from jira import JIRA

jira_options = {
   'server': '<your jira url>',
   'verify': True,
   'headers' : {
                    'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               }
}

jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, basic_auth=('<username>', '<password>'), validate=True)
```